# How do saved games on used DS's work?

Tags: nintendo-ds

If you buy Nintendo games pre-owned, will you start from the beginning or will the old owner's things still be saved on there? I'm a bit confused as to where the data is saved.

Comment: I assume by the tag, you want to know where data is stored for DS games?

Comment: Yes. I want to buy second hand games as thee cheaper but don't want other peoples halved finished games on them haha

Comment: Even if there is someone elses game on it when you buy it, you can just reset the game and start over

Comment: Is this easy to do? Does it take long?

Comment: It's usually very simple. Obviously this would depend on the game though.

Answer (score 1):

The game save data is stored on the card itself. However it does a data format is if it is on a different DS.

So, if you put a card in a different DS, it will have the same game data.

Also, if you are going to sell your game, be sure to erase the data.

Comment: What do you mean about the format?